# Does a "tetragonometry" as a branch of geometry exist?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm very aware that something like a tetragonometry would be (more or less) arbitrary since many geometric problems can be solved with trigonometry already. I still was wondering though: Does a branch of geometry like tetragonometry actually exist? By tetragonometry I mean a branch of mathematics that studies the relationships between side lengths and angles of quadrilateral instead of (like in trigonometry) triangles.

Comment: Surely you mean quadrilaterals rather than squares.  The relationship between side lengths of a square is incredibly trivial.

Comment: I never heard of something like tetragonometry; anyway, a quadrilateral can be divided into two triangles

Comment: As for relationship between sidelengths of a quadrilateral... note that a quadrilateral is just two triangles who share a side.  There doesn't really need to be a new branch of study dedicated to this since old techniques still apply.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oops, I meant quadrilaterals. Not squares. My bad.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton: There are certainly quadrilateral-specific relations one can study. There might even be clever ways to describe them with, say, "tetragrammic" counterparts of trig's sine and cosine and friends; however, consideration of such things requires accommodation for the fact that *similarity* (the engine that drive trig) is complicated for quads. Eg, any two triangles have "congruent corresponding angles" *if and only if* they have "proportional corresponding sides"; this is not generally true for quads.

Comment: I would say the next step after the triangle would be the tetrahedron.

Comment: Triangles are **rigid**, that's what makes them especially important.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton: Giving a boost to 3 dimensions, you can study four-vertex figures (ie, *tetrahedra*) and their dimensionally-enhanced trigonometry (eg, "[tetra]hedronometry"). For instance, if a tetrahedron has a "right corner" (with three edges at right angles), then the *areas* of its faces satisfy $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=W^2$, where face $W$ is opposite that corner. (This is [deGua's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem).) There are also Laws  of Cosines and whatnot. Some of my own research (especially non-Euclidean) is available via [hedronometry.com](http://hedronometry.com).

Comment: To add to @IvanNeretin 's perceptive comment, a triangle defines a plane (in various ways, but eg by barycentric co-ordinates). A quadrilateral need not be planar, and a general quadrilateral comprises four sides of a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why "tetragonometry" per se wouldn't be necessary is, as pointed out in the comments, we already have the trigonometric ratios, and in practice any quadrilateral can be sliced into two triangles to calculate its desired measurements.

It's also not clear what the "tetragonometric ratios of an angle" would be defined as, or how they would offer improvements in utility and comprehension over the familiar trig ones.

Basically any time you have a right angle somewhere in a diagram, you can draw in an auxiliary line and get yourself a right triangle to apply trig ratios to. And if you don't have one yet, you can frequently get a right angle by dropping a perpendicular. Most math students/engineers/physicists, in practice, probably wouldn't bother drawing in further auxiliary lines beyond that to create a quadrilateral so their diagram is set up perfectly to do "tetragonometry."